# Embed Picker directly on the page instead of a dropdown or popup

Tags: .net, maui

The `Picker` in .NET MAUI allows the user to select an item inside a popup or a dropdown. Is there a way to display the `Picker` directly in the page layout?

Current behavior:

[image: Current behavior]

Desired outcome:

[image: Desired outcome]

It appears the only way to implement this today is to implement a custom control using `CollectionView`.

Comment: Correct; you would have to roll your own to have it embedded. The Picker uses each platform's native control, that behaves the way you are seeing. Picker is designed to behave independently of a page's layout, and to only be visible when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can create a `style.xml` in the `Platform->Android->Resources->values`. Then put the code below to the style.xml.

```
<resources>
    
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/Theme.picker</item>
    
</style>

<style name="Theme.picker" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white </item>
    
    //all the dialog color
</style>
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    //number color
</style>
</resources>
```

Second, change the Theme name to match the style name like this in the `MainActivity.cs`.

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
```

Here is the sample:

[image]